# Assign FB Login action to custom button

Tags: html, facebook

I have a custom button on my webpage that i like to assign a FB login to.

The custom button (JS handler):

```
<div class="button_wrap">
            <a class="button_aLeft" id="button_aLeft"><span></span></a>
            <a class="button_bLeft slidebttn" id="button_bLeft">Login<span></span></a>
        </div>
```

Because the Facebook button holds a pretty long code i posted it on jfiddle:

[Facebook button](http://jsfiddle.net/QzdwE/3/)

Is it possible to assign the login action to the custom button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use login method of the JS SDK and run it onclick on your own button image ect.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: hmm.. didn't realize its that simple..thanx m8. i wil accept the answer once the 10 min' block is over